# Swift: using delegates to send data to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

How do I use delegates to send data to another view controller and then display it in the collection view? My problem is with moving the array across using delegates.

Below is an example of what I am working on.

When I use usersList in the ThirdViewController, I get an error that says  'Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value'

```
protocol ExampleDelegate {
    func delegateFunction(usersArray: Array<User>)   
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private var model: Users = ViewController.createAccount()
  var exampleDelegate: ExampleDelegate?


  @IBAction func ShowUsers(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let ShowUsersVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController

        var userList: Array<User> = model.listOfUsers
        exampleDelegate?.delegateFunction(usersArray: userList )

        present(ShowUsersVC, animated: true)
        
    }

}
```

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var usersList: Array<User>!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

    let GetUsersVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        GetUsersVC.showMomentsDelegate = self

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

    }
}


extension ThirdViewController: ExampleDelegate {
    func delegateFunction(usersArray: Array<User>)  
    usersList = usersArray
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need delegates in this case. You are sending data forwards, so just do it like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private var model: Users = ViewController.createAccount()
  var exampleDelegate: ExampleDelegate?


  @IBAction func showUsers(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let showUsersVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController

        var userList: Array<User> = model.listOfUsers
        showUsersVC.usersList = userList /// pass the data!

        present(showUsersVC, animated: true)
        
    }
}
```

Also in Swift you should lowercase objects like `userList`, as well as functions like `showUsers`.

Comment: Thank you! Do I only need a delegate if I were to send data back to the first View Controller? Or if the data I am sending back is altering the data in the model?

Comment: Whenever you send data back and/or alter the data (with a function) you need a delegate. Or closures, but delegates will be fine.